# MATLAB - Smooth heat map from (x, y, z) points within a triangle?

Tags: matlab

I have many 3D scatter points `(x, y, z)` that are guaranteed to be within a triangle. I now wish to visualize `z` as one **smooth** 2D heat map, where positions are given by `(x, y)`.

I can easily do it with `meshgrid` and `mesh`, *if* `(x, y)` together form a rectangle. Because I don't want anything falling outside of my triangle, I can't use `griddate` either.

Then how?

**MWE**

```
P = [0 1/sqrt(3); 0.5 -0.5/sqrt(3); -0.5 -0.5/sqrt(3)];
% Vertices
scatter(P(:, 1), P(:, 2), 100, 'ro');
hold on;
% Edges
for idx = 1:size(P, 1)-1
    plot([P(idx, 1) P(idx+1, 1)], [P(idx, 2) P(idx+1, 2)], 'r');
end
plot([P(end, 1) P(1, 1)], [P(end, 2) P(1, 2)], 'r');
% Sample points within the triangle
N = 1000; % Number of points
t = sqrt(rand(N, 1));
s = rand(N, 1);
sample_pts = (1-t)*P(1, :)+bsxfun(@times, ((1-s)*P(2, :)+s*P(3, :)), t);
% Colors for demo
C = ones(size(sample_pts, 1), 1).*sample_pts(:, 1);
% Scatter sample points
scatter(sample_pts(:, 1), sample_pts(:, 2), [], C, 'filled');
colorbar;
```

produces

[image]

**PS**

As suggested by Nitish, increasing number of points will do the trick. But is there a more computationally cheap way of doing so?

Comment: Looks like the function you are trying to visualize is `f(x,y) = x`. Is this your actual data?

Comment: @knedlsepp nope, but I have a function to map `(x, y)` to `z`. Just think of it as `z=x+y`!

Comment: But the function will be nonlinear I suppose?

Comment: @knedlsepp Yep, it is nonlinear, involving up to  `x*y`.

Comment: Ok. I would suggest triangulating the data and then plotting a [`trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html). (Or you could cheat and `surf` a rectangular mesh and then overlay a triangle-cutout from a white square.

Comment: have a look at http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html

Comment: @Jonas: If it is only about plotting it is a better idea to just plot a `trimesh` and let the graphics do the linear interpolation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangulate your 2D data points using [`delaunayTriangulation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html), evaluate your function with the points of the triangulation and then plot the resulting surface using [`trisurf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html):

After `%Colors for demo`, add this:

```
P = [P; sample_pts]; %// Add the edgepoints to the sample points, so we get a triangle.
f = @(X,Y) X; %// Defines the function to evaluate
%// Compute the triangulation
dt = delaunayTriangulation(P(:,1),P(:,2));
%// Plot a trisurf
P = dt.Points;
trisurf(dt.ConnectivityList, ...
        P(:,1), P(:,2), f(P(:,1),P(:,2)), ...
        'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
        'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
        'FaceLighting', 'phong');
%// A finer colormap gives more beautiful results:
colormap(jet(2^14)); %// Or use 'parula' instead of 'jet'
view(2);
```

The trick to make this graphic beautiful is to use `'FaceLighting'`,`'phong'` instead of `'gouraud'` and use a denser `colormap` than is usually used.

The following uses only `N = 100` sample points, but a fine `colormap` (using the now default `parula` colormap):
[image: Triangle mesh]

In comparison the default output for:

```
trisurf(dt.ConnectivityList, ...
        P(:,1), P(:,2), f(P(:,1),P(:,2)), ...
        'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
        'FaceColor', 'interp');
```

looks really ugly: (I'd say mainly because of the odd interpolation, but the `jet` colormap also has its downsides)

[image: Trisurf default]

Comment: actually, it's the horrible jet colormap that makes this ugly.

Comment: @Jonas: ;-) It's the default for all the older versions and `parula` is only available since 2013, so I left it to the reader.

Comment: there are plenty of good colormaps on FEX, such as the [perceptually improved colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28982-perceptually-improved-colormaps/content/pmkmp.m). Thank you for being kind to my eyes, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just increase `N` to make the grid "more smooth"? It will obviously be more computationally expensive but is probably better than extrapolation. Since this is a *simulation* where `s` and `t` are your inputs, you can alternately create a fine grids for them (depending on how they interact).

---

```
P = [0 1/sqrt(3); 0.5 -0.5/sqrt(3); -0.5 -0.5/sqrt(3)];
% Vertices
scatter(P(:, 1), P(:, 2), 100, 'ro');
hold on;
% Edges
for idx = 1:size(P, 1)-1
    plot([P(idx, 1) P(idx+1, 1)], [P(idx, 2) P(idx+1, 2)], 'r');
end
plot([P(end, 1) P(1, 1)], [P(end, 2) P(1, 2)], 'r');
% Sample points within the triangle
N = 100000; % Number of points
t = sqrt(rand(N, 1));
s = rand(N, 1);
sample_pts = (1-t)*P(1, :)+bsxfun(@times, ((1-s)*P(2, :)+s*P(3, :)), t);
% Colors for demo
C = ones(size(sample_pts, 1), 1).*sample_pts(:, 1);
% Scatter sample points
scatter(sample_pts(:, 1), sample_pts(:, 2), [], C, 'filled');
colorbar;
```

[image]

Comment: Right, indeed it is better than extrapolation. But, well well, too expensive. It will be my last resort though. Thanks!